# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

**Issue :** In the above code, i have used two specific print statements to do the same thing. While the first one does its job, the second one is throwing an exception while being executed. I have brain stormed it a lot but not able to find exactly where the None type object is coming from inside join:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

input_labels=['red','black','red','green','black','yellow','white']
encoder=preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(input_labels)

print("\nLabel Mapping:")
for i,item in enumerate(encoder.classes_):
    print(item, '--->',i)

print("\nLabel Mapping:",''.join(print(item, '--->',i) for i,item in 
enumerate(encoder.classes_)))
```

**Here is the output:**

```
Label Mapping:
black ---> 0
green ---> 1
red ---> 2
white ---> 3
yellow ---> 4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\satyaranjan.rout\workspace\archival script\bokehtest.py", line 12, in <module>

Label Mapping:
black ---> 0
green ---> 1
red ---> 2
white ---> 3
yellow ---> 4
    print("\nLabel Mapping:"),''.join(print(item, '--->',i) for i,item in enumerate(encoder.classes_))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Question : Both code blocks (line 8,9,10) and line 12 are doing the same functions . What is the issue here with the one liner(line 12) for which it is returning Nonetype object from with in join . If i want to remove it, what replacement can be performed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line

```
print("\nLabel Mapping:",''.join(print(item, '--->',i) for i,item in enumerate(encoder.classes_)))
```

into:

```
print("\nLabel Mapping:",''.join('%s--->%s' % (item, i) for i,item in enumerate(encoder.classes_)))
```

---

The return of print function is `None` so your code tries to join `None` elements,  that is why it gives an error. When you convert format them as string, the problem should be solved.